# why does my function returns an empty dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, charts, timeserieschart

Hey I'm trying to run my function on a time series data which is stored in a database.
After fetching the data from the database I run my charting function, it runs without any error.
But when I try to call it, it returns an empty dataframe.

**Here is the code**

```
import math

def Rangebaroperation(ticks,rangesize):
    #declare rangesize nad all important variables like hightarget and lowtarget & etc.

    highTarget = None 
    lowTarget = None
    lastClose = None
    rangesize = None
    tempHighTarget = None
    
    def createBar(close):
        newTick = {
            ['Open']: int(float(round(lastClose),2)),
            ['Close']: int(float(round(close),2)),
            ['High']: int(round(highTarget),2),
            ['Low']: int(round(lowTarget),2),
            }
        newTick[float['Close'][-1]] = newTick[float['Open']]
        
        def processMove(ticks,b):
            #declare the continuous direction of a trend like upwards or downwards.
            global rangesize
            global lowTarget
            global highTarget
            while (1):
                if (price < b):
                    #direction is upward
                    price = min(b,highTarget)
                    lowTarget = max(lowTarget , (price - rangesize))
                    if (b < highTarget): break
                elif (price >= b):
                    #direction is downward
                    price = max(b,lowTarget)
                    highTarget = min(highTarget , (price + rangesize))
                    if (b > lowTarget): break
                
                createBar(price)
                resetTargets()
                
                def resetTargets():
                    for tick in ticks:
                        
                        global tempHighTarget
                        global highTarget
                        global lowTarget
                        global lastClose
                        global rangesize

                        highTarget = price + rangesize
                        lowTarget = price - rangesize
                        lastClose = price
                        
                        for i in rangesize(0,len(tick)):
                            i=i+1
                            q = tick[i]
                            if not q: continue
                        q1 = tick[i - 1]
                        if not i:
                            if q1:
                                price = q1.newTick['Close']
                                if (price or price == 0): resetTargets()
                                
                        if not q1: continue
                        C = q.newTick['Close']
                        O = q.newTick['Open']
                        H = q.newTick['High']
                        L = q.newTick['Low']
                        if (not C and C != 0): continue
                        O = O if O or O == 0 else C
                        H = H if H or H == 0 else C
                        L = L if L or L == 0 else C
                        
                        if (not price and price!= 0):
                            start = math.floor(O / rangesize) * rangesize
                            price = O if start.isnumeric() else start
                            resetTargets()
                            processMove(q1, O)
                            
                        if (i): processMove(q, O)
                        #SHORTEST DISTANCE BETWEEN OPEN & EITHER HIGH OR LOW DETERMINES INITIAL DIRECTION.
                        if (H - O < O - L):
                            if (H): processMove(q, H)
                            if (L): processMove(q, L)
                        else:
                            if (L): processMove(q, L)
                            if (H): processMove(q, H)
                        
                        processMove(q, C)
                        if (i == len(tick) - 1 and C != lastClose):
                            tempHighTarget = highTarget
                            highTarget = lowTarget + rangesize
                            lowTarget = tempHighTarget - rangesize
                            createBar(C)
```

**And this is the code which i use to fetch data from the database and convert it to the charting pattern i need.**

```
db = sqlite3.connect('Z:/II.IV.XVI/GOALS/INTRADAY TRADING/TONY_STARK/ALGORITHM FILES/ticks.db')

def get_hist(ticker,db):
    token = instrumentLookup(instrument_df,ticker)
    data = pd.read_sql('''SELECT * FROM TOKEN%s WHERE ts >=  date() - '12 day';''' %token, con=db)
    data = data.set_index(['ts'])
    data.index = pd.to_datetime(data.index)
    ticks = data.loc[:, ['price']]
    df=ticks['price'].resample('5min').apply(Rangebaroperation,0.4).dropna()
    return df

candle_df = pd.DataFrame(get_hist("RELIANCE",db))
```

Why do I get an empty dataframe when I call this function?

**This is the sample input I apply in the code which is in the form of a dataframe**

```
ts                   price       
2020-12-09 13:39:12  2021.95
2020-12-09 13:39:13  2021.35
2020-12-09 13:39:14  2021.35
2020-12-09 13:39:15  2021.35
2020-12-09 13:39:16  2022.00
                     ...
2020-12-15 14:15:29  1975.75
2020-12-15 14:15:30  1975.95
2020-12-15 14:15:31  1975.90
2020-12-15 14:15:32  1975.90
2020-12-15 14:15:33  1975.95
```

**And this is the sample output I expected to receive (also in the form of a dataframe).**

```
ts                   open     high     low      close                                  
2020-12-09 13:35:00  2021.95  2022.10  2021.10  2021.30
2020-12-09 13:40:00  2021.30  2024.45  2021.05  2024.00
2020-12-09 13:45:00  2024.00  2024.25  2022.65  2023.95
2020-12-09 13:50:00  2024.00  2024.00  2022.50  2023.80
2020-12-09 13:55:00  2023.85  2025.00  2023.30  2024.90
2020-12-09 14:00:00  2024.85  2027.40  2024.80  2025.80
2020-12-09 14:05:00  2025.85  2029.00  2025.40  2027.00
2020-12-09 14:10:00  2026.65  2033.60  2026.25  2033.25
2020-12-09 14:15:00  2033.05  2033.80  2028.00  2030.70
2020-12-09 14:20:00  2030.35  2031.00  2026.10  2027.00
```

In this huge stackoverflow family can anyone help me in finding the error please.

Comment: While I haven't tried your code, it seems there are two problems first in the line ```df=ticks['price'].resample('5min').apply(Rangebaroperation,0.4).dropna()``` there seems to be a syntax error and needs to be rewritten as ```df=ticks['price'].resample('5min').apply(Rangebaroperation(0.4).dropna()```, Second I don't see where Rangebaroperation returns a result .

Comment: hey @itprorh66 thanks for your help and it would be great if you run this code on some form of data like a dictionary and then please tell me the error where am i lagging.

Comment: Since I have no idea what you are trying to accomplish, I wouldn't know right from wrong. This might be a good time for you to practice your debug skills. The following three references give excellent advice on debugging your code. [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/), [Six Debugging Techniques for Python Programmers](https://medium.com/techtofreedom/six-debugging-techniques-for-python-programmers-cb25a4baaf4b)  or [Ultimate Guide to Python Debugging](https://towardsdatascience.com/ultimate-guide-to-python-debugging-854dea731e1b)

Comment: hey @itprorh66 as i said in the question this is a conversion of time-series data into a rangebar charting pattern like renko or japanese candlestick you must have know about these things i think.
soo whenever i try to run this code it returns me an empty dataframe and this is just ruining my brain.

Comment: if you could please help me getting out of this then it would be very much appreciated.

Comment: If you could provide a sample of the input, a minimal reproducible example of the code and your expected output, maybe we could help you

Comment: Hey @itprorh66 thanks for your help & below is the sample of the input.

(ts                                 price)
(2020-12-09 13:39:12  2021.95)
(2020-12-09 13:39:13  2021.35)
(2020-12-09 13:39:14  2021.35)
(2020-12-09 13:39:15  2021.35)
(2020-12-09 13:39:16  2022.00)
(2020-12-15 14:15:29  1975.75)
(2020-12-15 14:15:30  1975.95)
(2020-12-15 14:15:31  1975.90)
(2020-12-15 14:15:32  1975.90)
(2020-12-15 14:15:33  1975.95)

Comment: And this is the expected output
(ts                                 open       high        low          close)                 
(2020-12-09 13:35:00  2021.95  2022.10  2021.10  2021.30)
(2020-12-09 13:40:00  2021.30  2024.45  2021.05  2024.00)
(2020-12-09 13:45:00  2024.00  2024.25  2022.65  2023.95)
(2020-12-09 13:50:00  2024.00  2024.00  2022.50  2023.80)
(2020-12-09 13:55:00  2023.85  2025.00  2023.30  2024.90)
(2020-12-09 14:00:00  2024.85  2027.40  2024.80  2025.80)
(2020-12-09 14:05:00  2025.85  2029.00  2025.40  2027.00)
(2020-12-09 14:10:00  2026.65  2033.60  2026.25  2033.25)

Comment: Could you please post the input and expected output into your original question as code, so it shows as a real table?

Comment: Hey @itprorh66 as you have said I've edited my question and you may please try to solve the error and any solution would be appreciated.

Comment: Okay, I loaded your dataframe and tried to execute the line ```df=ticks['price'].resample('5min').apply(Rangebaroperation,0.4).dropna()```, it indeed doesn't return anything.  The reason seems to be the definition of Rangebaroperation is malformed.  When called, Rangebaroperation has ticks and a rangesize of 0.4, it however never executes any of the lines after ```tempHighTarget = None```.  So you need to figure out how to reformat the code or determine what you are missing.

Comment: Hey @itprorh66 I've given my best in reformatting this code , rather if you could please suggest me some must edits in this code then it would be appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, the code is too convoluted for me to figure out, I have no idea